# What is the key strength reduction encrypting only 160 bits of data using RSA1024 for signatures?

Tags: rsa, signature, padding

I am attempting to determine the strength of an incorrectly implemented 1024 bit RSA signature scheme. The weakness in the implementation is that the padding data lacks random numbers. As a result, for every message signed, only 160 bits of data are changed (cryptographic hash).

How does one determine the resulting reduction of strength in the scheme, and how many signed messages would be necessary to make a 1024 bit private key a mathematically feasible operation to recover?

Comment: The PKCS#1 v1.5 signature scheme does not use randoms during signature creation, so your question might be void. It only uses randoms within PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption, and that is *mainly* used to protect plain text. The full mathematical and cryptographic answer is certainly something for crypto as Jason S suggests. When you ask the answer there, please provide more info on the actual scheme used as you cannot answer the question without that info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are no necessary 'reduction in strength', for two reasons:

- You ask about how many signatures you'd need to recover the private key.  Well, even with unrestricted Oracle access to the private operation, there's no known way to recover the private key (or equivalently, factor the modulus) that's more efficient than just ignoring the Oracle and attacking the modulus directly.  Hence, giving the attacker access to a limited number of signatures cannot help him recover the private key.
- What the attacker might be able to do with some padding methods is deduce the value of other signature operations; this would be generating a forgery without the private key.  Now, there are certainly known padding methods (such as a naive 'zero fill' method) that are prone to this.  On the other hand, there are deterministic padding methods (such as the [PKCS #1.5 RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-32) method) for which there is no known method of generating forgeries easier than finding collisions in the hash function.

So, if the system is using, say, the above PKCS method, there is no known weakness, even if the attacker has access to huge numbers of signatures.

Comment: I understood that introducing random data in the block to be RSA encrypted was necessary. So based on your answer, padding the cryptographic hash even with 0xff does not introduce any weaknesses into the system?

Comment: @hsikcah: introducing randomness is necessary for data encryption (before applying the public key operation), but is optional for signature production (before applying the private key operation). PKCS#1-v1.5 signs without randomness, and there is no known attack. ISO/IEC 9796-2 scheme 3 also signs without randomness, and even has a strong security proof.

Comment: @hsikcah: to answer your question about "padding the cryptographic hash with 0xff" with certainty, some details are missing on what happens on the very left. If the padding produces a value less than n (implying that the leftmost bit is forced to 0, not 1), likely your are safe. Same if the adversary can not realistically obtain the signature of many messages of _chosen_ content.

Comment: @hsikcah: Also, no matter how bad the padding scheme and how many signatures an adversary gets, the private key never leaks for that reason (that's a virtue of the odd exponent in RSA). What can happen is that an adversary could forge signatures of some messages, using the signatures of other messages.

Comment: Given that the public key and modulus are stored in a hardware device, it is sent some data and a signature. It uses the keys to decrypt the signature and compare it against a locally calculated cryptographic hash. I just happen to know that once decrypted the signature is a 160 bit hash preceeded by 0x1f 0xfffff....fff (864 bits of padding). I was hoping this could somehow be used to find a way to generate my own signature blocks that would correctly decrypt and validate.

Comment: Well, that would be a forgery.  Sorry, but we don't know a practical way to do that; about the only things to try would be to factor the modulus (you've got the public key, right?), or to find another SHA-1 preimage; either are believed to be doable with the current state of the art.

Comment: @poncho: Do you mean _undoable_ ? A second-preimage attack for SHA-1 is far out of the state of the art. And as of factoring a 1024-bit RSA modulus, in this century, the largest RSA modulus publicly factored has been at most (y-2000)*32+512 bit, and I think this will hold until 2015.

Comment: @hsikcah: The hardware device is supposed to apply the public key function to the signature $S$, yielding $T=S^e\bmod n$; then accepts or rejects the signature and data depending on if both (A) the hash of the data matches the appropriate 160 bits of $T$, and (B) all the other bits of $T$ are what they are supposed to be. (A) detects an alteration of data without a signature change, (B) prevents some attacks. [Poor implementation](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/dss/RSAstatement_10-12-06.pdf) of (B) [is not unknown](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/845620).

Answer (score 4):

Well, that is exactly how RSA signatures normally work. [PKCS#1 version 1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313) *block type 1* is the most common signature format used today. For block type 1, the padding is a constant string, and the data is the hash packaged in an ASN.1 structure that also identifies the signature algorithm.

More [modern signature schemes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447) incorporate a random component, but they are not nearly as widely supported yet.

Comment: GregS: String of constants, or string of constants for a certain key size and hash algorithm? The length of the string depends on the (structure around the) hash algorithm and of course the 3 byte overhead, so the string itself is not constant.

Comment: owlstead: You are correct, the amount of padding depends on the hash function and the key size. Rather than edit the answer, I'll just suggest that for full details the reader is encouraged to examine the RFCs linked to.

Comment: I guess that would suffice :)